# Kinect v2 Game Development in C#

Tags: c#, frameworks, xna, kinect, gestures

I'm trying to make a Kinect game using custom gestures and the Kinect v2. It should be able to detect a gesture then perform a certain action.

I only have experience in XNA but it seems like XNA cannot be used with the Kinect, or I just can't figure out how using XNA Refresh.

What is a good framework or library to use to make a simple 2D kinect game with custom gestures? Or, how do I get XNA to work with custom gestures.